# Memory leaks in List::MoreUtils' each_array() and each_arrayref()?

Tags: perl

I have just discovered a nasty memory leak using both each_array() and each_arrayref() from List::MoreUtils.

These three lines of code are part of a subroutine executed four thousand times on each run.
My objective is to give proper format to values already in a hash. I have a fixed number of hash keys and a format string for each hash key.

```
my %hash = ();
# ...
my $two_arrays = each_arrayref( $field_list, $field_list_format );
while ( my ( $field, $format ) = $two_arrays->() ) {
    $hash{ $field } = sprintf $format, $hash{ $field };
}
```

If I stick a `return;` before `my $two_arrays ...`, the leak disappears. The same `return;` past the last line makes the leak.

Since the subroutine is part of a daemon program, I noticed the continuous growth of memory ( both VIRT and RES ).

There is something I did wrong? Is there is any memory leak of each_array() or each_arrayref(), I'm not aware of?

- List::MoreUtil ( VERSION 0.22 )
- Perl 5.12.1 ( x86_64 with threads ) on Linux 2.6.32-32-generic ( Ubuntu 10.04 )

Comment: Note: sticking `return;` before the while loop keeps the leak.
A comment to `$hash{ $field } = ...` keeps the leak.
It seems that `$two_arrays` iterator does not give back what it takes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

List::MoreUtil ( VERSION 0.22 ) is dated July 2006, 5 years ago. The current version is 0.32, is the leak still present in this version? There have been several memory leaks fixed in the last few versions: http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/ADAMK/List-MoreUtils-0.32/Changes

Comment: Well mirod, that's it!

I have just done the upgrade and the leak disappeared. I owe you another one ^_^.

Comment: it's always a good idea to look at the bug reports on a module. And to be fair, version 0.22 is from 2006, but the next version is dated September 2010, so it's not that old, and it may still be included in a few linux distributions.

Comment: You're right. I don't know how, I assumed that perl I have built myself, had the most recent CPAN modules.
I have built the 5.12.1 version a few days after release date... How did I manage get that old version?

Comment: since perl 5.12.1 was released in May 2010, at the time List::MoreUtils 0.22 was the current version

Comment: Time has passed very fast. I have learned the lesson: next time I'll double check module documentation for changes.