# Perl memory leak from match operator

Tags: perl, debugging, memory-leaks

While investigating a long running perl program for memory leaks I tried to use [Test::LeakTrace](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Test%3a%3aLeakTrace).

Looking at one of the leaks it reports I can narrow down the leaking code to just:

```
/$?/
```

So running: `perl -MTest::LeakTrace::Script -e'/$?/'` prints:

leaked SCALAR(0x10d3d48) from -e line 1.

Why is this, do I need to worry about it ?

**Update:** Also tried [Devel::LeakTrace::Fast](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Devel-LeakTrace-Fast/lib/Devel/LeakTrace/Fast.pm), it's not complaining about the same code.

Comment: `Test::LeakTrace` does't like regular expressions:

    perl -MTest::LeakTrace::Script -E 'my $regexp = qr/abc/'
    leaked ARRAY(0x193cd80) from -e line 1.
    leaked HASH(0x195d730) from -e line 1.
    leaked SCALAR(0x195d700) from -e line 1.

Comment: @MarcoDeLellis So you think it's a bug in Test::LeakTrace ?

Comment: I don't have any proof of bugs int that module, but it makes me think about false positives. Maybe there are circular references in your code, or there is an old module version that leaks memory, as it happened [to me](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6438266/memory-leaks-in-listmoreutils-each-array-and-each-arrayref) some time ago.

Comment: Run it in a huge loop to determine if it is actually leaking memory.  I've found Devel::LeakTrace as having lots of non-problem output.

Comment: I would use an alternative tool to check how much is the leak, a process manager or like

Comment: Do you have any evidence of a leak besides a warning?

Comment: @briandfoy No, I think it isn't a leak. But would be nice to nail down whether it's actually a bug/flaw in Test::LeakTrace.

Comment: there have been reports of memory leaks caused by a bug in the regex engine in perl 5.10  - http://www.gossamer-threads.com/lists/perl/porters/232045

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you got a leak. Then this:

```
perl -e'/$?/ for 1..1E9'
```

should make your process grow in memory

```
 ps -o rss,vsz <PID>
```

In my case it stays stable all the way. You should check it for your setup.  It could be that leak your module detects is some late destruction. You could write a note to the module authors to help you figure out its output, you can help them to improve it...

BTW another thing confirming "no leak" for me is that on

```
 perl -MTest::LeakTrace::Script -e'/$?/ for 1..1000'
```

I don't see multiple leaked scalars, just one.